# Will expanding foam improve soundproofing around Interior Doors

Tags: doors, sound-proofing, renovation

I'm re-casing my interior doors. Is there any value to using an expanding spray-foam between the jamb and the rough-in?

If it reduces noise transfer, I'm in. But I don't want to waste money or make future work harder than it needs to be.

This house was cheap 1980s construction. There is no insulation in the interior walls. The interior doors are flimsy flat hollow-core doors - worse than the faux-panel type which dominate the market now.

What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that'll help unless you have solid-core doors, door and threshold seals, and sound insulation in your walls already. Without those things the quantity of sound coming through your casing (on both sides) is negligible.

What foam *will* do is make the door mount much more secure. If your doors aren't hung well with appropriate nails and/or screws they can jiggle quite a bit in operation. Foam is an easy fix for that.